# Unregister / update a package on a private bower registry

Tags: javascript, redis, bower

I have my own bower registry for my company private packages.
I use this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-registry
The problem is that I can't find a way to unregister or update an existing package.
I tried registering it again using:

```
bower register my-repo https://bitbucket.org/x/myRepo.git
```

But it prints: `EDUPLICATE Duplicate package`

Tried sending the following curl request:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://bower.internal-server/packages/my-repo"
```

But it says that it can't delete, with no reason.

Any help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a deletion feature to the bower registry..
Available in this repo: 
https://github.com/taykey/bower-registry

Opened a pull request to the original repository.

Answer (score 1):

As the same bower log states:

> $ bower EUNKNOWN      Can only unregister packages hosted on GitHub.com

You need to access the databaase directly and delete the row for that package in the `packages` table.